# Python import pandas infinite loop on task scheduler

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, windows-task-scheduler

I have this script that works fine when executed manually. Problem is that when I Windows Task Scheduler It seems to hang somewhere.

The task is executed by a service account with privileges to run as a batch job, and has full control over the Anaconda3 folder.

```
import pandas as pd
print("Hello")
```

I tried to execute this to show some log on what's happening at it seems like the problem is when importing pandas.

```
python -m trace --trace script.py > logfile.log
```

Comment: Can you check the task history and add the error details to the question?

Comment: There is no error details as I have to end the task and kill the python.exe manually through Task Manager. It just gets stuck there. With the trace option the logfile just bloats and bloats until I stop the task.

Comment: I went through the logs today and I see that there seems to be repeated calls to tempfile.py and random.py until I just kill the process as it never ends. I'm not sure which part of the pandas module also calls it

Comment: I had the same problem, even though pandas as a library was installed properly and the script runs fine when manually run from the command line